# i want to use switch case in jquery to move the layout from one place to another while clicking buttons. this is my code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to do a switch case and move the object according to the buttons in jquery

```
 $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
     switch(this.id){
         case 'moveright':
             $(".layout3").css({left:"735px"});
         break;
         case 'movebottom':
             $(".layout3").css({top: "850px"});
             break;
     }
 });
```

this is my 
'https://jsfiddle.net/4v4e5rjc/'

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
     switch(this.id){
     case 'moveright':
        $(".layout3").css({"margin-left":"735px"});
        break;
     case 'movebottom':
         $(".layout3").css({"margin-top": "850px"});
        break;
     }
});
```

Comment: @varoon : share ur html code here.. may b some problem with html

Comment: its der in the jsfiddle link below